# Why are there fake lockers in the school?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-homecoming

In *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, Peter stows his old suit and his extra web fluid under/behind a bank of fake lockers (I can't find an image online of the frame where he does this, but he lifts it from the bottom on 2 separate occasions in the film). This event is referenced in [this](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Spider-Man) recap.

Why would his school have a wall full of fake lockers?

Comment: A real person can't lift a bank of real lockers by hand. A Spider-Person could. That's kind of the point/joke.

Comment: Even if, with Spider powers he could rip them out of the wall, they wouldn't slide up neatly.

Comment: @rosends: You can't know that they were attached to the wall in the first place. Just because you haven't seen a freestanding locker, does not mean it does not exist. We had them in our school, for example.

Comment: I know free standing lockers. We have them in our school as well. But most are recessed in walls.

Comment: "the only locker systems I know are...." - are you a locker scholar with encyclopedic knowledge of all locker systems ever made in the history of locker-making throughout the world?  If not, then that statement doesn't tell me much.

Comment: Actually, in my 20 years working as a High School teacher and administrator, I have had extensive experience with a variety of locker systems (including locksets). So is it encyclopedic? No. Is it more than just passing? Yes, substantially.

Comment: So you lockers were used by spider-powered superheroes? *Dramatic Licence*... *Suspension of Disbelief*. I'd start there.

Comment: I don't now - they kept their secret superhero identities a secret. If we use suspension of disbelief as a blanket answer, then anything is possible and Spiderman can walk through walls. When we read stories, we expect certain in-universe consistency.

Comment: There might or might not be, depending on the type of lockers. A universe which has weight and friction (as evidenced in other scenes) and which has building built like the "real" universe's buildings would expect something from the lifting up of real lockers in a wall. A high school with aware students would have people who might notice lockers have been moved. Peter's backpack keeps getting thrown out with the garbage so people are aware of surroundings and not magically blind for convenience's sake.

Comment: it sounds to me like you've decided _a priori_ that you found a logical flaw in the movie and refuse to accept that maybe you didn't. That's not a very good way to go about asking questions.

Comment: Actually, what I have said is that I might have, but lacking the evidence (screen shot) that shows I haven't I have to wonder. A great answer would include an image from the movie which would explain this so that my assumption is undercut and the question rendered DOA.

Comment: Without any particular evidence either way, neither is more likely than the other. The school is more likely to have a superhero as a student, and negligent teachers on a criminal level than would happen in the real world, so I guess anything is possible. Remember, it's a movie (cf suspension of disbelief).

Answer (score 16):

They're not fake lockers. It's a row of real lockers that Peter has somehow detached from whatever holds it in place, and is lifting up in the air. In Peter's school, the lockers are inset into the walls in between the classroom doors, as are the ones in this photo:

[image]

Note that this is a single piece of metal: the lockers have been welded together and there's a single pane of metal covering the entire row. It's also likely there's a single supporting base across the entire bottom.

When Peter lifts the lockers up, he grabs the bottom lip and lifts straight up. There's about a two foot gap between the lockers and the ceiling, and they slide upward as he lifts. As is typical with super strong heros, Peter also has an impeccable sense of balance, allowing him to lift and hold the lockers one-handed without them tipping forward. (The same power lets, e.g. Superman hold an airplane up by it's nose.)

On the walls to either side of these lockers, there are very clear scratch marks and gashes in the drywall. This indicates that the sides of the locker are scraping against the walls, which you can also hear when he lifts them up. That makes it unlikely that he's installed any kind of device to help smooth the movement -- he's just brute-forcing it.

Comment: I don't have a still from the film, but I recall thinking that they were recessed, more like http://www.hallowell-list.com/images/lockers/accessories/locker-reccessed-trim.png

Comment: the fact that Peter lifts them up in the air without breaking the walls or ceiling would strongly indicate that you're misremembering.

Comment: Could be, but the fact that not a single bit of dust flies around when they are lifted indicates that the sliding mechanism was without any frictional losses.

Comment: Yes, let's nitpick the physics and realism of dust in a movie about a boy who gains superpowers after being bitten by a radioactive spider.

Comment: Yes, no one on this site assesses the physics implications of events in superhero movies... https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/12153/how-does-superman-accelerate-when-he-flies-in-man-of-steel

Comment: People asking how Superman's powers work is not even remotely the same as nitpicking the amount of dust kicked up by lifting lockers.

Comment: This is probably not remotely the same according to you either https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/26618/how-is-the-voice-not-distorted-when-barry-is-running-at-super-speeds/27561#27561 I guess I just look for more consistency in my films.

Comment: Asking how the Flash's powers work is not even remotely the same as nitpicking the amount of dust kicked up by lifting lockers.

Comment: maybe the school just has a really good janitorial staff.

Comment: To be fair, the school custodial staff keeping things dust-free-clean ***would*** require the greatest suspension of disbelief out all issues raised relating to this question.

Comment: I watched the movie again to be sure; they are definitely like the ones in the photo.